# Proof of a variation of the monotone convergence theorem where fn<f but fn isn't necessarily increasing.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

That's basically all of it. $f_n$ and $f$ are all measurable and non-negative, $f_n\to f$ and $f_n\le f$, i want to prove that $\int_Rf=lim{\int_Rf_n}$ for $n\to \infty$ (Lebesgue integral). I know there's a way to prove this using the monotone convergence theorem, but I can't seem to find it.

EDIT: added non-negative

Comment: you should not edit questions in such a way that existing answers become incorrect by the edit.

Comment: Yes, I am terribly sorry I forgot to add it.

Comment: Next time you  can just leave the question as it is and create a new one with the changes applied. This is less unfair towards people which take their time to answer your questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true. Consider $f(x) = 1$ for $0<x \le 1$ and $=0$ everywhere else.

Then consider $f_n$ which is $=1 $ on $[\frac{1}{n},1]$, $=-n$ on $(0,\frac{1}{n})$ and $= 0$ everywhere else. Then $f_n \rightarrow f $ but $\int f_n = 0 \neq \int f =1$.

**Edit after change in the question:** for nonnegative $f_n$ Fatou's Lemma applies which implies the claim (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742183/show-that-int-mathbbrf-lim-n-to-infty-int-mathbbrf-n-given/1742194#1742194)).

Comment: My bad, forgot to say the functions were non negative.